# Why does ActiveSheet.FilterMode returns False when sheet has filter?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, listobject

I'm using the following code in an attempt to detect a filter applied to a column in a table and then clear the filter:

```
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

According to Microsoft documentation:

> This property is true if the worksheet contains a filtered list in which there are hidden rows.

This doesn't seem to be the case since `ActiveSheet.Filtermode` only returns `True` if a cell inside the table where the filter is applied is selected.

- First question: Is the documentation wrong? [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.filtermode.aspx)
- Second question: Is my only option to select a cell inside the table to get the expression to return True?

PS I am using Excel 2010

Edit: Answer to Question 2, Non-select based methods to clear filters...

`If ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Autofilter.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Autofilter.Showalldata`

Comment: `ActiveSheet` refers to the currently active sheet and may differ to the one you might think is active. Add `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name` to see which sheet VBA is referring to. Anyway, you should start coding more explicitly and should use `ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("The_sheet_that_I_want").FilterMode` instead. Oh, and please don't add relevant information in comment. Rather [edit your original post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) and add the relevant tag [Excel-2010] to your post. Afterwards, you can also delete your comment.

Comment: can't you just use `ActiveSheet.ShowAllData` without the if? My guess is that if the filter is not applied to the whole sheet but just part of it, it can return false.

Comment: used Debug.Print to verify that the window is active on execution, still returns False with filter applied in table.

Comment: @Slai `ActiveSheet.ShowAllData` without the If gives: "Run-time error '1004': ShowAllData method of Worksheet class failed" when cell outside the table is selected at execution, works if cell in table is selected at execution.

Comment: Is it actual Excel Table that is in the `Worksheet.ListObjects` ?

Comment: @Slai yes, definitely a properly formatted table that is recognized as a ListObject

Comment: then you can just loop the ListObjects http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=151761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can replicate both your issues on Excel 2013: both the buggy `False` on `FilterMode` and the error on `ShowAllData`.

In response to whether the documentation is wrong, I would say that it is *missing* a qualification to say that the `ActiveCell` should be in the `ListObject`s `DataBodyRange`. Perhaps the documentation is correct but that this is a bug that has not been addressed. Maybe you can update your question with a link to the documentation?

Re your second question - I agree that using this workaround is the most obvious solution. It seems a bit unpleasant to use `Select` but sometimes I guess this cannot be avoided.

This is how I did it using the `Intersect` function to check it the `ActiveCell` is currently in the area of the `DataBodyRange` of the `ListObject`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lst As ListObject

    'get ActiveCell reference
    Set rng = ActiveCell

    'get reference to Worksheet based on ActiveCell
    Set ws = rng.Parent

    'is there a Listobject on the ActiveCells sheet?
    If ws.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
        Set lst = ws.ListObjects(1)
    Else
        Debug.Print "No table found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'is cell is in the DataBodyRange of ListObject?
    If Intersect(rng, lst.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        'set the ActiveCell to be in the DataBodyRange
        lst.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Select
    End If

    'now you can safely call ShowAllData
    If ws.FilterMode = True Then
        ws.ShowAllData
    End If

End Sub
```

### Edit

Further to @orson's comment:

> What happens if you skip the If Intersect(rng, lst.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then and use If lst.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then lst.AutoFilter.ShowAllData End If ?

So, you can check the `FilterMode` of the `ListObject` itself and then as long as you have a reference to the `ListObject` you can use his code:

```
If lst.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then 
    lst.AutoFilter.ShowAllData 
End If
```

Comment: @ Robin Mackenzie What happens if you skip the `If Intersect(rng, lst.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then` and use `If lst.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then lst.AutoFilter.ShowAllData End If` ?

Comment: @orson - that works irrespective of where the cell is. The work-around I've posted only applies if you are trying to use `FilterMode` and `ShowAllData` with a `Worksheet` per your question which references `ActiveSheet`. I will update my answer with an edit referencing your comment.

Answer (score 2):

An easier alternative can be to just `AutoFit` all rows:

```
Rows.AutoFit
```

The issue with that is that it will un-hide and auto fit all rows on the active sheet.

---

Update from http://www.contextures.com/excelautofilterlist.html

```
Dim list As ListObject

For Each list ActiveSheet.ListObjects
    If list.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
        list.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Suggest to add:
`On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0` before and after the `For Each...Next` 
or `On Error Resume Next` at the beginning if this corresponds to a standalone function. 
This is needed because if any of the ListObjects does not have and `AutoFilter` an error will be triggered.

Comment: @EEM Thanks. I updated it to supposedly not error, but can't test it.