# Excel VBA Reset multiple advanced filters with ShowAllData

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am using 3 advanced filters in a worksheet and I want to reset all 3 tables. Using showAllData only resets the last table. I have tried unhiding the filtered rows without success. Perhaps I should loop through all 3 tables?

```
Sub ClearFilter()
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems as though you will need to filter your range1 (table) work with the data and then clear it, then the same for Range2, same for Range3.  The clear is only going to work on the most recent filter used, it does not buffer them in memory for one undo.  You could write a macro that undoes all 3. by sleecting the range again and clearing filter (I believe, untested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `ShowAllData` clears the filters from the last table, you can unhide the remaining hidden rows to show all the data like this...

```
Sub ClearFilter()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    ActiveSheet.Rows.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: @Waimea You're welcome! Does the solution you accepted works for you?

Comment: Okay. But why would you prefer to loop through the tables to disable the filters while the solution I proposed is straight forward and doesn't require any looping?

Comment: I prefer your solution and I changed the green arrow accordingly!

Comment: @Waimea Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

`IF Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.FilterMode = True THEN Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.ShowAllData`

Substitute the sheet and table names you have.  You need the `IF` statment to check if there are filters set, otherwise it will error when you try to clear filters that are not there.

For further reading, see: [Why does ActiveSheet.FilterMode returns False when sheet has filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184392/why-does-activesheet-filtermode-returns-false-when-sheet-has-filter)